# How can I solve uper bound limits with only lower bound limits - Linear programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, optimal-control

My linear programmer use the Simplex method.

$$\text {max}: c^T x\\
\text{s.t} \\
Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0
$$

I have heard that it's possible to reforumlate the subject so it will solve for both uper bound limit and lower bound limit only for $Ax$. Can I write my subject too function as:

$$
\text {max}: c^T \begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{s.t} 
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A &0 \\ 
0 & A 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1
\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix}
b_u\\ 
-b_l
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

But here is the hard part...this will not work.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$

Any suggestions? Or do you think I can run two simulations after each other? One with $b = b_u$ and one with $b_l$ ?

Comment: Many LP solvers allow both lower and upper bounds on $Ax$, and these are called *range constraints*.  They are handled directly in the simplex method, without explicitly duplicating the number of constraints.

Comment: @RobPratt Johan Löfberg gave me a solution to that problem. I hope thats working :)

Comment: Yes, it works.  But I'm saying that it is inefficient and maybe unnecessary, depending on your solver.

Comment: @RobPratt Hmm Yes I understand. The reason why I selected this solver is because I solve my numerical problems on a "computer" of 20 kB RAM and 64 kB Flash ;) It need to be simple. Tried quadratic programming solver for a year ago. Did not work well onto that machine.

Comment: @RobPratt Look up "linprog" here https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/Algebra.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b_l \leq Ax \leq b_u$ is 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\ 
-A 
\end{bmatrix}x \leq \begin{bmatrix}
b_u\\ 
-b_l
\end{bmatrix} 
$

Comment: Good! Thanks. Is there a way to tell the simplex method to ignore the constraints on $x$ vector?

Comment: Oh! See now that that would not be needed! Only change the $Ax \leq b$ constraints.